# should i create a new db for every new wordpress site i develop?

Tags: wordpress

> Hi,
>
> > let say im creating a wordpress site, and ofcourse have a database, so the database is populated with the current site, and i have migrate the site and database to the host, now im about to develop a new wordpress site, should i create a new database for it? or create it using the available database? 
> >     im assuming that i should have a new database for the new website but i want to hear the experts point of view.
> >     thanks

Comment: You don't have to, but I would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what are these sites for. For example, I create custom WP sites and templates. Lots of them. And I need to show the clients how they work before installing, so I have a dev server. In that particular case, I use the same DB and simply change

```
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';
```

to something else

But of course, if you're doing this for sites that will actually have traffic and you plan to work with, then it's way better to use a different DB for each site unless your host limits you. If you ever have to move your site, you probably won't face the dreaded "50 Mb DB limit", you'll have a cleaner and faster DB, and many more advantages with 0 disadvantages